# Devise Sanitization of Quote Escaped JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I have a Rails 4.0 server running with Devise Authentication. I have my Devise controllers set to accept JSON. When i make an AJAX request from the browser to sign up a new user, everything works fine. The parameters in this case look like:

```
{"user"=>{"username"=>"Firstuser", "email"=>"theuser@email.com", "password"=>"mysecret",   "password_confirmation"=>"mysecret"}}
```

BUT! when i try submitting parameters that look like this:

```
{"user"=>"{\"username\":\"Seconduser\",\"email\":\"user2@email.com\",\"password\":\"mysecret\",\"password_confirmation\":\"mysecret\"}"}
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `permit' for #<String:0x007f9183dc1290>:
```

in my server log. My application controller's parameter sanitization is set up like this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters      
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }      
end
```

Anyone know what I should do from here? I'm not sure where in the Devise pipeline i may need to use JSON.parse(params), **IF** that would even work

thank you for any insight!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I figured it out:
When submitted the first way, the object i was attempting to sanitize and configure_permitted_parameters was of type ActionController::Parameters. But, when submitted the second way, the object was a string which has no 'permit' method (the ActionController::Parameters does).

I basically have to check to see what kind of parameters are coming in:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters     
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
    if u.class == String
      u = ActionController::Parameters.new(JSON.parse(u))
    end

    u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```